# wxPython need to add scrollbar to StaticBox; is this possible?

Tags: python, scroll, wxpython

I have seen similar questions however none have helped me with my specific problem.

I have a bunch of different StaticBoxes on a wx.Panel.  I dynamically add TextFields to one particular StaticBox.  If I add too many, because the BoxSizer is set to wx.VERTICAL (which is what I want), the Panel extends to an ugly look.  Is it possible to add a scrollbar to a StaticBox?  The only scrollable objects I have found are wx.Panel and wx.Window.

[image: The reason I use wx.VERTICAL, a good example]

[image: Why I would like to use a scrollbar in staticbox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you put the `StaticBox` in a `ScrolledPanel`? That would work perfectly. Here's a simple example:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

########################################################################
class MyPanel(scrolled.ScrolledPanel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        super(MyPanel, self).__init__(parent,
                                      style = wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.SetupScrolling()

        box = wx.StaticBox(self, label="Test Box")
        bsizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(box, wx.VERTICAL)

        for i in range(15):
            txt = wx.TextCtrl(self)
            bsizer.Add(txt, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        main_sizer.Add(bsizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)


########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(None, title="Static")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You can use a top level panel and then add a left panel and a right panel as children to the top panel where the right panel would be the scrolled panel instance. That would be one valid approach.

Comment: For some reason I was thinking that a panel was a frame.  Totally screwed me up.  I used a modification of this without setting up the class with the constructor as the TextCtrl's are added dynamically after the mainframe is loaded.  Thank you sir.